# Discrepancy in Predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0

Q1: I have a matrix of dimensions 44 and 5, representing 5 feature vectors. I have defined two models: the first one is the basic neural network structure, and the second one uses a convolutional layer. I don’t have a very good understanding of the input layer and size. So, I need some feedback to confirm if the code is correct.

```
X_train = np.random.rand(44, 5)
y_train = np.random.rand(44, 1)
X_rem = np.random.rand(11, 5)
X_train= np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32)
X_rem= np.asarray(X_rem).astype(np.float32)
y_train= np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
BATCH_SIZE = 44
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_rem, y_rem))
```

.

```
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(5,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

.

```
model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(1, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

```
model1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.2),
                  loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
```

```
model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.2),
                  loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
```

Q2: If the code is correct, I have a matrix of dimensions (44, 5). Then, why is the input shape specified as (5,)? I understand that the model expects the input shape in the format (Batch size, height, width). However, I haven't reshaped them before.

Q3: Why do I get same value for all the values in X_rem after using 'model1.predict(X_rem)' and 'model2.predict(X_rem)'? Is there a difference in usage between the two functions 'model1.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)' and 'model1.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100)'?

I tried to reshape the input data before defining the model. I never fully understood the concept behind it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Q1 : Yes, the code is correct.

Q2: The input shape is defined as `(5,)` because you are using `Conv1D`. If you use `Conv2D` then you need to add one dimension more.

When using `Conv1d` , the convolution takes place on one axis (the first axis).
When using `Conv2D`, the convolution uses 2 dimensions, so 2 axis.
```

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011510/is-there-any-difference-between-conv1din-out-kernel-size-1-and-conv2din-ou) the answer.

Q3: You receive the same value for 2 reasons:

1. You have a very big learning rate, so the model can't get the gradients right.
2. You use `Conv1d` with just 1 filter, so you just pass the values of the array. If  you omit this layer or use for example `tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(10, kernel_size=1, activation='relu')`, you will see that you don't get the same values.

The `train_dataset` is a tensorflow dataset and there is no difference when calling fit, if you use `X_train and y_train`. It is more efficient though.

This code works:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

X_train = np.random.rand(44, 5)
y_train = np.random.rand(44, 1)
X_rem = np.random.rand(11, 5)
y_rem = np.random.rand(11, 1)

X_train= np.asarray(X_train).astype(np.float32)
X_rem= np.asarray(X_rem).astype(np.float32)
y_train= np.asarray(y_train).astype(np.float32)

BATCH_SIZE = 44



model1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(5,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(5,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((5, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(10, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(12, activation='linear'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model1.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])

model2.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
                  loss='mean_absolute_error',
                  metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])


model1.fit(X_train, y_train)
model2.fit(X_train, y_train)

a = model1.predict(X_rem)
b = model2.predict(X_rem)

print(a)
print(b)    


[[-0.15530916]
 [-0.02674089]
 [ 0.02004206]
 [-0.15770614]
 [-0.07137147]
 [-0.5538231 ]
 [-0.40441772]
 [ 0.10797038]
 [ 0.12479986]
 [ 0.13209383]
 [-0.31992483]]
[[0.4927392 ]
 [0.36021274]
 [0.50080335]
 [0.5790647 ]
 [0.5881373 ]
 [0.17355554]
 [0.14454347]
 [0.38594624]
 [0.61323386]
 [0.58704513]
 [0.6550123 ]]
```

Comment: Hi, I decreased the learning rate to 0.0001 for both models. In model2, I increased the filter size to 10. I am still getting the same values. I increased the number of epochs, but that did not change the results.

Comment: Hi @Alok I posted the code that works. Check it